# XML reading from web and displaying content

Tags: c#, xml, streamreader, xmlreader

I'm reading a file like from the web:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<eveapi version="2">
  <currentTime>2011-07-30 16:08:53</currentTime>
  <result>
    <rowset name="characters" key="characterID" columns="name,characterID,corporationName,corporationID">
      <row name="Conqrad Echerie" characterID="91048359" corporationName="Federal Navy Academy" corporationID="1000168" />
    </rowset>
  </result>
  <cachedUntil>2011-07-30 17:05:48</cachedUntil>
</eveapi>
```

im still new to XML and i see there are many ways to read XML data, is there a certain way im going to want to do this? what i want to do is load all the data into a StreamReader? and then use get; set; to pull the data later?

Comment: Search or google parsing xml in C#

Answer (score 1):

If you want object-based access, put the example xml in a file and run

```
xsd.exe my.xml
xsd.exe my.xsd /classes
```

this will create my.cs which is an object model similar to the xml that you can use with XmlSerializer:

```
var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(eveapi));
var obj = (eveapi)ser.Deserialize(source);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use XmlReader Class or XmlTextReader Class

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa720470(v=vs.71).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextreader(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use the data in the easy way, especially when you're new to XML, use `XmlDocument`.
To load the document:

```
using System.Xml;
using System.IO;
public class someclass {
    void somemethod () {
        //Initiate the XmlDocument object
        XmlDocument xdoc;
        //To load from file
        xdoc.Load("SomeFolder\\SomeFile.xml");
        //Or to load from XmlTextReader, from a file for example
        FileStream fs = FileStream("SomeFolder\\SomeFile.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(fs);
        xdoc.Load(reader);
        //In fact, you can load the stream directly
        xdoc.Load(fs);

        //Or, you can load from a string
        xdoc.LoadXml(@"<rootElement>
                    <element1>value1</element1>
                    <element2>value2</element2>
                    </rootElement>");
    }
}
```

I personally find `XmlDocument` far easier to use for navigating an Xml file.

To use it efficiently, you need to learn XPath. For example, to get the name of the first `row`:

```
string name = xdoc.SelectSingleNode("/eveapi/result/rowset/row").Attribute["name"].InnerText;
```

or even more XPath:

```
string name = xdoc.SelectSingleNode("/eveapi/result/rowset/row/@name").InnerText;
```

you can even filter:

```
XmlNodeList elems = xdoc.SelectNodes("//*[@name=\"characters\"]")
```

gives you the `rowset` element.

But that's off topic.